# Can I configure the rate of garbage collection python?

Tags: python, linux, macos, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have a python program and it was getting killed due to an out of memory error. I was using some deep recursion so i decided to use `gc.collect()` at the beginning to the method.

This solved the problem but and the program is no longer killed. Does anyone know why I had to call garbage collector and it wasn't automatically taken care of?

Now I worry that this is slowing down my program and I wonder is there a way to configure how/how often garbage collection is complete from outside my application? (without calling `gc.collect()` from the code)

PS. this was not a problem on my macos, only when I deployed the code to a linux VM on GCP

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is no way we can possibly guess. It is almost certain that the real reason for getting an out of memory error is an inappropriate algorithm, or a bug. But we can only possibly diagnose code that we can actually see.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! I understand that I shouldn't need to use it, but I thought it was extremely strange that I never had an issue with the code running it locally, but then the memory exploded when I ran it on a linux vm, and then the solution was to use `gc.collect`. My code is complex but in essence it's a class with a recursive algorithm and some global variables.

Comment: Maybe this can help : https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/gc.html#gc.threshold

Comment: It would be helpful to gather more data so that it is easy to understand why explicit garbage collection was needed.  As seen on https://stackoverflow.com/q/72252150 , one reason that garbage collection can be needed is that  cycles of python objects indirectly are keeping larger buffers that are kept in memory due to references from  those cycles but those larger buffers don't factor into the logic as to when to do garbage collection.   Could you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?