# Do I need to free array and dataframe memory in jupyter notebook (python 3)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, memory-leaks

Do I have to manually free arrays and dataframes as in C and C++?

I'm currently working on large arrays (thousands*thousands) with about 100~300 MB in csv.
I'm using Jupyter notebook (pythons3) to do normalizations and other data handling, and have run my codes hundreds of times.
I'm new to python, and it only recently occurred to me that memory leak might be happening. (I'm not having any errors)

I've read up a bit on gc.collect() but had trouble understanding.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: No, in Python, you don't need to manage the memory by yourself. Python will handle all this by itself.

Comment: Python doesn't allow you to "free memory", Python is a fully memory managed langauge

Comment: `gc.collect()` does not free memory, it runs the *auxilliary* garbage collector in CPython, that handles reference cycles (CPython uses reference counting as it's main garbage collection strategy.). You probably will never ever have to use this.

Comment: The general case where one might have to use gc.collect() is when the algorithm to determine when to look to break cycles doesn't cause breaking the cycles to happen soon enough.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71699162/why-does-ctypes-cast-appear-to-trigger-a-memory-leak/72252150#72252150 for an example where an explicit call to gc.collect() is needed.